# accessing JQuery.getJSON data with URLs as objects

Tags: jquery, getjson

Is there any way to access **jQuery.getJSON** data with *URLs* as objects?
Here's the response I get from getJSON call:

```
{"http://example.com/example":"value",
"http://example2.com/example":"value2"}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is this the response you get from `getJSON` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

For example:

```
var h = {
 "http://yahoo.com" : "good"
};
alert(h['http://yahoo.com']);
```

In your case, you might want to loop through the items using a for..in statement like:

```
var h = {
 "http://yahoo.com" : "good",
 "http://google.com" : "better"
};
for(var key in h) {
 alert(key+" => "+h[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all the object which you have in the question is invalid, you cannot have semicolon inside the object definition. You should use comma to separate the object properties.

```
var obj = {"http://example.com/example":"value",
"http://example2.com/example":"value2"};
```

You can access the above object's properties like this.

```
alert(obj["http://example.com/example"]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EW9D3/